# How can I save an orgmode buffer/file to a different file

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, org-mode

because the regular ("save-as") key-binding C-x C-w does not work in org-mode.
How can I switch between standard and org-mode keybinndings?

Comment: It works for me.. have you changed the keybinding yourself?

Comment: Manually run `write-file` perhaps?

Comment: What does `C-h k C-x C-w` give?

Comment: It gives me: "C-x C-w runs the command ido-write-file, which is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `ido.el'.
It is bound to C-x C-w, <menu-bar> <file> <write-file>..."
And that makes sense. After reopening emacs (and the .org file) it worked. Not sure what I messed up but thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: (1) Please, do not be so hasty with questions at stackoverflow. Doublecheck beforehand. (2) Please, write your comment as answer to mark this question answered. Thanks in advance, Tobias.